# Connect a display in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I need some help in working out how to enable a display in c++ with the displays preferred settings. From what I have gathered I should use **SetDisplayConfig** to do this.

My code so far:

```
UINT32 NumPathArrayElements = 0;
UINT32 NumModeInfoArrayElements = 0;
LONG error = GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATHS,&NumPathArrayElements,&NumModeInfoArrayElements); 
std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO> PathInfoArray(NumPathArrayElements);
std::vector<DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO> ModeInfoArray(NumModeInfoArrayElements);
error = QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_ONLY_ACTIVE_PATHS,&NumPathArrayElements, &PathInfoArray[0],&NumModeInfoArrayElements, &ModeInfoArray[0],NULL);


for(unsigned int i=0;i<PathInfoArray.size();++i){
    if(PathInfoArray[i].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx<ModeInfoArray.size()){
        int modeIndex=PathInfoArray[i].sourceInfo.modeInfoIdx;
        if(itIsADisplayIWantToWorkWith){
            //Disable
            //PathInfoArray[i].flags=0;
            //Modify
            //ModeInfoArray[modeIndex].sourceMode.position.x=-1920;
            //Enable...?!
        }
    }
}
//Save
SetDisplayConfig(NumPathArrayElements, &PathInfoArray[0],NumModeInfoArrayElements, &ModeInfoArray[0],(SDC_APPLY | SDC_ALLOW_CHANGES | SDC_USE_SUPPLIED_DISPLAY_CONFIG));
```

Any form of clue as to where to look for this is appreciated, I don't feel like mixing **ChangeDisplaySettingsEx**(managed to enable the display with hard coded settings) with **SetDisplayConfig** unless I am forced to.

MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285671%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Something wrong with Control Panel?

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The question is how do I enable a display that is currently disabled.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the control panel. But in my scenario(wanting to change the setup dynamically) that is not really an option.